# How to reconfigure openbox from a different configuration file

Tags: configuration, openbox

Once an openbox session is running, `ps ax | grep openbox` shows that it has been started from `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. Now, `openbox --reconfigure` will re-read this file and apply any changes made in it. Can it be reconfigured with a different configuration file stored somewhere else? If not, would the option `--reset` do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into openbox's manual? Or running:

```
openbox --help
```

Note that there is the option `--config-file`. Although I am not personally in need of multiple configurations I can think of so many situations it would be much appreciated. So the next time you need a different configuration just replace your normal `openbox --replace` with `openbox --config-file <path to some other config file> --replace`

If you want that other configuration to load with your Lubuntu session I think you should add a delayed autostart command in $HOME/.config/openbox/autostart. Something like: `sleep 5 ; openbox --config-file <path to some other config file> --replace &`

But honestly if you need only one configuration file, just make a back-up of your current one ($HOME/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml) and edit it to whatever your heart desires.